# Using WebClient to post data to an SSRS reporting server

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012

I'm trying to connect to an SSRS server and get report data via .NET webClient.  I'm doing this because I can't use forms and I don't want to just send the user to the report server.  I'd rather keep everything in my web application.

So I have this bit of code in a controller:

```
public IHttpActionResult GetSpecs(int Id)
{               
     var client = new WebClient();
     client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "pw", "domain");
     var data = client.DownloadString(ReportServerUrl + "?%2fFactory+Specs+Reports%2fSpecs_Stats_Matrix&rs:Command=Render&a=" + Id + "&b=" + CurrentUser.Id);
     return Ok(data)
}
```

It successfully connects to the SSRS server, and it does get data.  Inspecting the data, it looks like it's the report I need, but it's just one giant string of html and javascript that the SSRS server spits out.

My question is, is there a good way of handling this data?

I'm in unfamiliar territory, and it doesn't seem like a lot of people interact with SSRS in this way.

I'm not quite sure how to display all the data the end user.

Thanks!

Comment: Why not use the SSRS WebService?

Comment: @DavidTansey I'm not familiar with SOAP at all so that's why I avoided it.

Comment: You can generate a proxy class for .NET for the SSRS WebService which will hide / abstract most of the SOAP pain-points away.  This is the approach used in almost any example of C# / SSRS WebService calls -- don't let the SOAP part scare you away.

Comment: @DavidTansey thanks, looking through the documentation now...however,I'm not sure if this is a way to display reports that need parameters passed to them.  This looks like it's only for management and subscriptions.

Comment: SSRS is a fantastic Reporting tool and Microsoft as usual makes it really easy to use. I did this same thing long time back in 2007 when we had to display the reports in our application and hide the ssrs server from end user. So we had to write a reverse proxy to handle all click events e.g sort, filter and then in the background we used to connect the ssrs server and get the report chunks and stream it back to the client.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thats quite easy. :)

First you need some assemblies to access the reporting service.

[image: Assemblies]

All these assemblies are easy to include in your project via Nuget,

[image: NuGet]

After this you need to connect to your SSRS service instance like this:

```
using Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms;

CustomReportCredentials reportServerCredentials = new CustomReportCredentials("User", "Password", "REPORTINGSERVER");

ServerReport report = new ServerReport()
{
    ReportServerUrl = new Uri("https://reporting.xxxx.com/ReportServer"),
    ReportServerCredentials = reportServerCredentials,
    ReportPath = "/Reports/MyReport",
    Timeout = 200000
};
```

Ask the service for supported render extentions and generate the report:

```
var renderExtentions = report.ListRenderingExtensions();
report.SetParameters(new ReportParameter[]
{
    new ReportParameter("parameter1", dcStringID.ToString()),
    new ReportParameter("parameter2", begin.ToString()),
    new ReportParameter("parameter3", end.ToString())
});

String mineType = String.Empty;
String fileNameExtention = String.Empty;

Stream stream = report.Render(renderExtentions.First(), null, null, out mineType, out fileNameExtention);
```

At this point you will have all you need. Stream, mine type, file extention.